# How can an expression be different from however paarenthesized?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this statement:

```python
> False == False in [False]
True
```

However:

```python
> (False == False) in [False]
False
> False == (False in [False])
False
```

It is incredible. What's the reason and the interpretation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[dis.dis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to the rescue and a bit of my interpretation.

Anyway, it looks like this. Consider three expression `X, Y, Z` and two operators `O1, O2`. Then

```
X O1 Y O2 Z
```

is equivalent to

```
(X O1 Y) and (Y O2 Z)
```

as can be seen by

```
a < b < c
```

example. I find this behaviour very counterintuitive.

And [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Note that `in` is a comparison operator.

Comment: An impressive answer.